# React - Uncaught Invariant Violation:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run my code on browser, I'm getting this error message.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: MyComponent.render(): A valid React
>   element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined,
>   an array or some other invalid object.

I'm using Atom as my code editor and running on a chrome web server. Here is my code.

```
<body>
<div id="react-comp"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return
          <div>
            <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>

          </div>;
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <MyComponent text="Hello World"/>
        <MyComponent text="Hello"/>
      </div>  
    , document.getElementById('react-comp'));


  </script>
</body>
```

It might be a jsx transforming issue? or any other thing?

Comment: You could use the non-minified version to see the full error message.

Comment: @Jack Now I can see the full error message. Description updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely hitting JavaScripts automatic semicolon insertion after `return`. Just remove the line break before your div.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div> // Change this line
        <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>

      </div>;
  }
});
```

Comment: It's working fine now! Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of React you are using, as I know some old version makes error if the JSX syntax isn't wrapped with ().
Try to do this on MyComponent's render method:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your render function to

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>    
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Daniel's suggestion is also correct.